# tup :: [String] -> [(Int, Int)]

Tags: haskell

I want to create a function which takes in a list ["1","2","3","4"] and returns a list of tuples [(1,2),(3,4)], but im not sure how to code it

```
every n xs = case drop (n-1) xs of
              (y:ys) -> y : every n ys
              [] -> []

tup :: [String] -> [(Int, Int)]
tup xs = [((read c),(read i)) | c <- (every 1 xs), i <-(every 2 xs)]
```

is what ive tried but the output is wrong

output:

```
*Main> tup ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
[(1,2),(1,4),(2,2),(2,4),(3,2),(3,4),(4,2),(4,4)]
```

Comment: So the tuple `(3,4)` should be left out, right?

Comment: it was a typo, meant [(1,2),(3,4)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use pattern matching:

```
tup [] = []
tup [_] = []
tup (a:b:other) = (read a, read b):(tup other)
```

The first two cases deal with the empty list and a list of one element. It doesn't make sense to construct a list of tuples out of these, so the function just returns the empty list. The last case simply extracts the two leading values, puts them into a tuple and prepends it to whatever the recursive call returns.